# add a pdf in cms page and make it downoldable magento 2

Tags: magento2, pdf

I want to add a pdf in home page and when i clck on it ,i can downold it. So how to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly upload pdf file from image uploaded in Magento however you can upload your pdf file in this location `Magento_root/pub/media/wysiwyg/` by any `ftp` or `sftp` client like `filezilla` or `winscp` and use below link to create download for your file in csm pages.

```
<a href="{{media url="wysiwyg/yourfile.pdf"}}" download="Filename">Download Pdf</a>
```

Comment: thanks a lot can you please tell me how to add icon of pfd and when i clcik on pdf it open a popup containning the pdf and i can downold this pdf

Comment: i want to have a cliquable catalog  to a downloadable animated PDF file